# vba ODBC refreshing

Tags: excel, vba, odbc

I got a problem with waiting for my query refresh until further code execution.

```
ThisWorkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").Refresh
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").ODBCConnection.refreshing 'Prints True
While ThisWorkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").ODBCConnection.refreshing
DoEvents
Wend
Debug.Print "updated"
[...]
```

It seems like ThisWorkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").ODBCConnection.refreshing is never turning false as the data connection doesn't finish while the macro is running.

I have another query depending on the result of another query (first ODBC connection and then UNION all with some additional data from Excel)
I can't block Excel for the query runtime, therefore BackgroundRefresh: False is not an option.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using

```
Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim con As ODBCConnection
Set con = ThisWorkbook.Connections("ConnectionName").ODBCConnection
con.BackgroundQuery = False
con.Refresh
```